# Return true if only if the lines are all not start with spaces

Tags: python, startswith

```
lines = files.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if not line.startswith(' '):
        res = True
    if line.startswith(' '):
        res = False
return res
```

This is my code, however, it returns True for at least one line is not starting with space. How do I fix it so it will return True if only if every line in the file I opened starts with something other than space. If at least one line starts with a space then return False.

Comment: What this code actually does, is return false or true according to whether the *last* line begins with a space. Each time around the loop you write a value to `res`, which means that all but the last value is overwritten. That's why it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Try: `all(map(lambda x:  not x.startswith(' '), open('/home/mnit/Desktop/file')))`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: one-liners are all very well, but that code might behave badly on Python implementations other than CPython. The problem is that the file doesn't get closed until the object returned by `open` is garbage-collected. On CPython that's immediate thanks to ref-counting, but not all Python implementations work that way. The "approved" way to use files is in `with` statements.

Comment: @SteveJessop Oh! I didn't know this problem. I learn this technique some day back on SO only (and I like it). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

**Demo:**

```
>>> lines = ['a', ' b', ' d']
>>> all(not x.startswith(' ') for x in lines)
False
>>> lines = ['a', 'b', 'd']
>>> all(not x.startswith(' ') for x in lines)
True
```

Also there's no need to load all lines in memory, simply iterate over the file object:

```
with open('filename') as f:
   res = all(not line.startswith(' ') for line in f)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in.

```
return all(not line.startswith(' ') for line in lines)
```

The [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function from the docs:

> ```
> all(iterable) -> bool
>
> Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
> If the iterable is empty, return True.
> ```

---

You could also use the `any` built-in in the same manner.

```
return not any(line.startswith(' ') for line in lines)
```

The `any()` function from the docs:

> ```
> any(iterable) -> bool
>
> Return True if bool(x) is True for any x in the iterable.
> If the iterable is empty, return False.
> ```

Comment: Or equivalently, `return not any(line.startswith(' ') for line in lines)`. In English I'd probably say "no line starts with a space" more often than I'd say "every line doesn't start with a space", but the questioner has said the latter in English so `all` is the right code for them :-)

Comment: The advantage to using `all(not line ...)` is that it shortcircuits the moment it gets to a line that *does* start with a space, whereas if I were to do `not any(line ...)` it would first iterate everything, and then check for validity. Meaning that including the condition `not` *within* the `all` is much more efficient.

Comment: That's not correct. `any` also short-circuits, ending the first time it encounters a true condition. So it will stop on the same line that your `all` stops, the first that starts with a space.

Comment: Yes, I misread your comment as `not all(line ...)` You are correct as well, though it doesn't really matter which option is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('filename') as f:
    res = True
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(' '):
            res = False
            break
return res
```